# How do I print the username using session in cakephp?

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I cannot get my username to show on the website when I call it form the session.

The code on the index page is:

```
<h1>Users Home</h1>
Welcome <?php $user = $this->Session->read('Users.username');?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried various other ways of calling it and then getting different error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are setting $user with the content of the username. But you are not printing it.

```
<h1>Users Home</h1>
Welcome <?=$this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')?>
```

which is short for

```
<h1>Users Home</h1>
Welcome <?php print $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username'); ?>
```

Comment: A minor thought. Is this vulnerable to XSS? Can a user register itself with something like `<script>alert('bloep');</script>HelloMyNameContainsAScript`? IDK cakePHP at all regarding this. But usually it is wise to filter 'user-created-content', which also involves user names.

Comment: dont use <?= - use <?php echo. also use h() to prevent XSS: `<?php echo h($this->Session->read('Auth.User.username'));?>`

Comment: any reason for advising against <?=

Comment: I'd advise in favor of using `<?=`... It's very convenient and the more people use it the less the chance they will take it away from us  ;)

Comment: @StijndeWitt > Considering it's always on as of PHP 5.4, you don't need to worry about them taking it away.

Answer (score 3):

As Hugo said you should do the following:

```
<h1>Users Home</h1>
Welcome <?php echo $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username'); ?>
```

If you are going to use it on more than one view, I would suggest you to add the following on **AppController**.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->set('username', AuthComponent::user('username'));
    // OR $this->set('username', $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username'));
}
```

And then on any of your view just use the variable $username to print the current username.

```
<?php echo $username; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username');
```

Or if you are using Cakephp 2.x you can use `AuthComponent::user('username')` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

After getting $user, you should do a echo $user or print_r($user) and you'll get the username printed.